# How to detect when a maximum number is rolled?

Tags: python, if-statement, random

This question seems like it would be easily answered by just making an if statement for my maximum in the range, BUT please take a second to read before calling me an idiot. I am making a program that lets the user choose between many different dice. I am wondering if there is an easy way to detect when the maximum value is rolled from any of the options without setting if statements for all of the different dice.

```
def inphandle(choice):
    if choice==4:
        roll = random.randint(1,4)
    elif choice==6:
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
    elif choice==8:
        roll = random.randint(1,8)
    elif choice==10:
        roll = random.randint(1,10)
    elif choice==20:
        roll = random.randint(1,20)
    return roll

def dice(roll):
    min = 0
    if roll==1:
        print("Min roll! Try again!")
        min = min+1
    if roll 


def mainmenu():
    print("Please choose from the following options:")
    print("Roll | EXIT")
    option = input()
    if option=="EXIT" or option=="exit" or option=="Exit"
        print("You rolled" + max + "max rolls and " + min + " min rolls! Goodbye!")

def main():
    choice = int(input("Please enter a number corresponding to the number of faces on your dice. E.x. 4 for 4-Sided: "))
    cont = input("Would you like to roll the dice? Y or N: ")
    while cont=="y" or cont=="Y":
        roll = inphandle(choice)
        dice(roll)
        cont = input("Would you like to roll again? Y or N: ")
    while cont=="n" or cont=="N":
        easteregg()
        cont = input("Do I get bunus points now?!?")
main()
```

I do have random imported, but this is simply a section of the whole program. I understand if there is no shortcut to this, but I wanted to check before typing it all out since it might not be necessary.

Comment: I'm confused because `def dice(roll):` is incomplete and returns nothing, and I'm not sure where you want to check if a maximum is returned. It's not clear what we should be looking at.

Comment: The maximum value for the current dice is `choice`, just compare with the rolled value.

Answer (score 0):

first change `inphandle`

```
def inphandle(choice):
    return random.randint(1,choice)
```

and then change

```
    while cont=="y" or cont=="Y":
        roll = inphandle(choice)
        dice(roll,choice)

   ...
 def dice(roll,max_val):
       if roll == max_val:print "MAX"
       elif roll == 1:print "MIN"
```

Comment: well, do not use `max` for argument name ;)

Comment: lol good catch ... allthough fwiw since i dont ever actually use the builtin and it only shadows it locally ... (still bad to do that...(although i wouldnt mind if they put in their homework with the max arg))

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest creating a class which handles different types of dice:

```
class Die(object):
    def __init__(self, num_faces):
        self.num_faces = num_faces

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.num_faces)

    def is_min(self, number):
        return number == 1

    def is_max(self, number):
        return number == self.num_faces
```

I would say this is a valid situation for that and you get to learn about classes ;)

Then use the class:

```
def main():
    minimums = maximums = 0
    choice = int(input("Please enter a number corresponding to the"
                       " number of faces on your dice. E.x. 4 for 4-Sided: "))
    die = Die(choice)
    cont = input("Would you like to roll the dice? Y or N: ")
    while cont.lower() == "y":
        number = die.roll()
        if die.is_min(number):
            minimums += 1
        if die.is_max(number):
            maximums += 1
        cont = input("Would you like to roll again? Y or N: ")

main()
```

Note that I moved your `min` & `max` counters to main, because the alternative is to make globals which is bad.

I also renamed them, because `min` and `max` are names of built-in functions. It is better to learn not to hide those.

Comment: It's a good practice (i think) to reduce `while cont=="y" or cont=="Y":` to `while cont.lower() == 'y'`.

Comment: @Nf4r Absolutely. I'll change that too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

change the inphandle to this:

```
def inphandle(choice):
  roll = random.randrange(1,choice+1,1)
  return roll
```

And change main() to:

```
def main():
  choice = int(input("Please enter a number corresponding to the number of faces on your dice. E.x. 4 for 4-Sided: "))
  valid_inputs = [4,6,8,10,12]
  if choice not in valid_inputs:
    print('Valid inputs are: 4,6,8,10,12. Try again.')
    main()
  cont = input("Would you like to roll the dice? Y or N: ")
  while cont=="y" or cont=="Y":
    roll = inphandle(choice)
    dice(roll)
    cont = input("Would you like to roll again? Y or N: ")
  while cont=="n" or cont=="N":
    easteregg()
    cont = input("Do I get bunus points now?!?")
```

Just a bit of clarification on the random.randrange:

```
random,randrange('from','to','increments')
```

from is the minimum value and to is the maximum value EXCEPT it self.
so if u want a range of 1 to 4, put 1 to 5.
increment: put 1 for increments of "1", so possible outputs with be 1, 2, 3 or 4 instead of like 1.3252342 or 2.446211

Comment: The recursive call to `main()` is an error. Python has a recursion depth limit, which means that a user who enters `3` many times eventually causes an exception. This should be a `while choice not in valid_inputs` loop instead.

Comment: hm, learn something new every day! Makes sense to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
def inphandle(choice):
    roll = random.randint(1, choice)
    return roll == choice
```

Comment: There are failing errors in this code e.g. look at `def dice(roll):`. How does this answer "detect when the maximum value is rolled from any of the options"?

Comment: i guess you got the downvote (I gave you +1)because while your suggestion is a huge improvement ... it doesnt answer the posters actual question

Comment: @JoranBeasley I gave the downvote for the reason stated in my comment.